# Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports and Visual Studio 2015 Build Error

Tags: delphi, visual-studio-2015

We have been using Robert Giesecke's excellent Unmanaged Exports library for a while with our Delphi application.  We just upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and it doesn't seem to be working anymore--I can compile the exact same project in VS2013 and it works fine, can access the functions in the DLL, etc.  I recompile in VS2015 (exact same code and project) and I get a build failure on the Unmanaged Exports library as shown below:

```
Task Parameter:SdkPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\ (TaskId:44)
Cannot find lib.exe in 'K:\Visual Studio 2015\Common7\IDE\\..\..\VC\bin'. (TaskId:44)
Done executing task "DllExportAppDomainIsolatedTask" -- FAILED. (TaskId:44)
Done building target "RGieseckeDllExport" in project "BWSITwilio.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:73)
```

And as such the library will not export the functions in the DLL for me to access in Delphi.  I can stay in VS2013 for a while but something seems amiss with the library in VS2015 (maybe looking in the NETFX 4.6 folder??)

I am open to ideas so I can use VS2015--I was about to uninstall 2013 but have to hold off now.

Thanks in advance for any input or advice--it is really this library that has allowed us to continue to use Delphi since we can access anything in .NET with it!

Comment: Have you tried tracking down the author? From the error message, it looks like `lib.exe` was moved within the VS installation tree from where this tool expected it to be, or perhaps it was eliminated entirely from VS2015 (I don't have it installed yet).

Comment: For me `lib.exe` lives in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin` on my Full Install Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. Which edition of Visual Studio 2015 are you using?

Comment: Why don't you target a lower .net runtime? Robert's using some unsupported magic and will need time to catch up I guess Robert is here on the Stack so you could ping him. I think that's the way forward. C++/CLI mixed mode would allow you to escape this dependency.

Comment: The path to `lib.exe` clearly doesn't match what the project is expecting. Find the bad path (the one indicated in the error message) and correct it to the proper location for `lib.exe` in your VS2015 install.

Comment: @Ken How is the asker going to do that? The asker has no control over the behaviour of the third party UnmanagedExports. Only Robert can fix it.

Comment: @David: If it's looking for `lib.exe`, it's trying to add object files to a library. A makefile or build script does that, so you find the build script or makefile. Unless you're telling me that Robert hard-coded a path to an executable in his library and is executing it from code in the library...?

Comment: @Ken Robert's tool is quite sophisticated. I'm not sure it's easy to modify it from the outside.

Comment: @Ken FWIW it is using lib.exe to build a .lib import library rather than working with objects. The latest version of UE no longer fails the build if lib.exe cannot be found.

Comment: @David it isn't the "magic"  that needs updating (that code is very old) ,  it's MS not providing a future-proof way of finding ildasm that forces me to update it. lib.exe should have been optional from the start.

Comment: @Robert I see. Btw, why is ildasm needed? Does your tool diassemble, modify the il, and then reassemble?

Comment: yes, I don't feel comfortable doing that with anything except the official tools. There's a lot that has to be considered: native thunks,  pdb etc.  IlAsm does that quite reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release notes for version 1.2.7 (dated 16 August 2015) on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) include this:

> no longer fails the build when it can't find lib.exe

I suspect you are using an older version and can solve your problem by moving to the latest.

You are probably using a version that was built before VS 2015 was released and I'm sure Robert's latest version now supports VS 2015.

For what it's worth, even if `lib.exe` still cannot be found that's not going to bother you since you don't need a .lib file to import into Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and was able to solve this by manually copying over some Visual Studio 2013 files into the 2015 folder. I searched for `lib.exe` on my computer and used Beyond Compare with the two application's program file directories.

- Open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\` in
  Explorer, select all files, Copy.
- Open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\` in Explorer, Paste. When prompted to replace, choose Skip.

After doing this I was able to compile my projects that were using `RGiesecke.DllExport` in Visual Studio 2015 again.

I can't tell you what specific version of 2013 I had installed because I've since uninstalled, but apparently these files are leftover. I'm running MS VS Community 2015 Version 14.0.23107.0.

Not sure if its relevant at all, but the `lib.exe` I copied from the 2013 bin folder's version reads 12.0.21005.1.

Comment: Further info: this happens if don't install the C++ libraries. Professional and higher does this automatically, but Express does not.

Comment: I have to down vote this terrible advice. Defacing the bin directory is not the solution. Please remove this post. You will only mislead others.